# Get my real location via ip address in IONIC without using GPS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to get my location using the ip address of my internet connection, I CAN NOT USE GPS. With 4g networks my location is too distant to my current city, this happens with a wifi connection (using the apic compiled by ionic) (tested on a samsung galaxy s7). An example could be, I'm in san francisco and it appears to me that I'm located in new york.

To get the ip address I am using this plugin:

Cordova-plugin-networkinterface, (when using network 4g, I do not know why my ip address does not appear, this with wifi network does not happen)

```
https://github.com/salbahra/cordova-plugin-networkinterface
```

I also use pages like:

http://ipv4.myexternalip.com/json43

http://wtfismyip.com/text48
     
        http://api.ipify.org/?format=text36
     
        http://myexternalip.com/raw38

When obtaining the ip by means of this plugin, or by one of these pages, I use pages like for example

http://www.ip2location.com/

to obtain my location.

But my location is not correct or at least nearby, it is always in other cities.
What I can do?

Comment: Nothing you can do about it with this approach

Comment: why friend, what is the problem?

Comment: your location is not correct or at least nearby, it is always in other cities

Comment: it depends on the api-provider in terms of accuracy but nowadays ip geolocation has got the worst accuracy compared to other means of geolocalisation for instance gps, wlan etc, it can successfully localize you in the right country though.